# Combining multiple Maven goals into one transaction (e.g. deploy and site-deploy, what if site-deploy fails?)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, transactions

I configured the build server to do

`clean javadoc:jar deploy site-deploy`

Now if site-deploy fails (because the site did not build, or somebody used the wrong parent pom), the build server shows a failed build, but the deploy was already applied.

Is there a way to "combine" deploy and site-deploy in a transactional way?

Or should I use a different chain of goals/phases (e.g. `install` before `site-deploy`)?

Comment: So, if it is some kind of build server related question, then you should tag it with the server name. I guess no one who knows the answer, will read it this way.

Comment: It is just a Maven command chain that we call from our build server (Quickbuild) but it would be the same for Jenkins, Bamboo etc.

Comment: I guess, then you have to write your rollback method and trigger it according  the maven commands exit code.

Comment: I am probably not the first guy who wants to do deploy and site-deploy in one build.

Comment: How about doing it bash script as below?
`mvn clean install site-deploy && mvn deploy`. Though this will fail in case of network error while publishing the artifacts.

Comment: Further if you do not want to build the project one more time, then use `mvn deploy:deploy-file`

Answer (score 7):

Here I am proposing a close solution with the help bash `&&` operator

```
mvn clean javadoc:jar install site-deploy && mvn deploy:deploy-file {PARAM}
```

This will let you

- fails the build if any of the goal fails during `install` phase
- if site-deploy fails, then your artifact will not be pushed/deployed to your remote repository
- no need to write any custom rollback mechanism if `site-deploy` fails

The only case this will fail is when your `deploy` goal fails, there will be no rollback `site-deploy`. I think failure of `deploy` phase will be very much rare.

Comment: _"failure of deploy phase will be very much rare"_ How do we know? Still what if `deploy` fails and the `site-deploy` works? This only solves a specific example of the transactional problem.

Comment: As per my understanding `deploy` might be failed due to below reason( may be more, but this comes to my mind first) 1) remote repository not accessible 2) network issue 3) network security rules (upload size). I have clearly mentioned above that this is `close solution` and if in my solution `deploy` fails, there will no `rollback` of `site-deploy`.

Answer (score 3):

`deploy` and `site-deploy` are usually done over HTTP and potentially deploy to different places, so achieving transactional semantics is probably impossible and you need to approach this as an eventual consistency problem.

In a CI context (that you mentioned you are using), if `site-deploy` fails, you'd need to either:

- rollback the `deploy`;
- retry the `site-deploy` goal.

I'm not familiar with quickbuild but with other common CI tools you are able to split the tasks into separate jobs to make it easy to apply either solution.

Since the goal (pun intended) seems to be to catch errors while building the site, an option might be to create a chain of jobs:

1. `mvn install site` to run regular tests and build the site;
2. two jobs that run in parallel and can be retried if failed:

   - `mvn deploy`;
   - `mvn site-deploy`.

This could more or less complex depending on how the workspace is shared between jobs.

Comment: Retrying site-deploy often makes no sense if the error is not the network, but the creation of the site fails due to problems in the pom or the source code. Rolling back deploy is also no really good idea because the artifact might have been already used/downloaded when you try to delete it from Nexus.

Comment: Then what you're probably after is a stage that runs `install site` to catch those problems, then two others that run `deploy` and `site-deploy` (which can run in parallel and be retried if failing).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could find using Maven core features is through the Release Plugin's [rollback](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/rollback-mojo.html) goal. This however implies that you'd better change the original build command to use the Release Plugin as well, since [this page](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html) in the documentation mentions the following:

> To rollback a release, the following requirement must be met:
>
> - You haven't run `release:clean` on the project. This means that **the backup files and the release descriptor from the previous release command still exists**.

However, it seems it is easy to do this, as the Release Plugin's [perform](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) goal already executes `deploy site-deploy` by default which is exactly what you are doing. As for the `javadoc:jar` goal, it can be attached to the release profile as mentioned in [this FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/faq.html#How_to_deploy_Javadoc_jar_file).

If for some reason, the Release Plugin could not be used, then I think the only way to get around this is through the build environment itself. You could split the build into two stages:

1. The first stage runs the `deploy` goal.
2. The second stage run `site-deploy`.

In case the second stage fails, you *manually* rollback by executing the first stage but against the previous revision in your SCM (the one that was last deployed successfully).

Comment: release:clean only reverts changes on the project and SVN. It cannot revert deployments to Nexus (which is probably impossible from Maven). The problem with your second approach is the same: Deployment cannot easily be reverted. I understand that a truly transactional behaviour is probably impossible. Maybe I should use `install site deploy site-deploy` so that in most cases, the build fails before the deploy.

Comment: @JFMeier That's weird. I think Maven should rollback on the remote repo as well when we execute `release:rollback`. Maybe someone should request this feature. For the second approach, yes it is definitely much harder to implement. But like I mentioned, the deployment revert can be done manually by re-deploying the last revision that was successfully deployed on Nexus (it's not a "revert" per se, more of a re-deploy on older SCM rev). But this requires splitting the build into phases to have fine-grained control over the build steps (which is a better thing to do IMO).